# Get multiple components instead of one. They are rendered from the list. vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of `instruments` that should render a `c-input` with `autosuggest` window when the user types something. Also, I need an option for `c-input` to add or remove `autosuggest` component.

```
/* instrument component */

<template>
    <c-input ref="input"
      :values="inputValue"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      @input="onInput"
      @change="onChangeInput"
      @reset="reset" />
    <autosuggest
      v-if="showSuggests"
      :inputValue="inputValue"
      :suggests="suggests"
      @onSelectRic="selectRicFromList"
    ></autosuggest>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'instrument',
    data: () => ({
      suggests: [],
      inputValue: '',
    }),
    computed: {
      showSuggests() {
        return this.isNeedAutosuggest && this.showList;
      },
      showList() {
        return this.$store.state.autosuggest.show;
      },
      isloading() {
        return this.$store.state.instruments.showLoading;
      },
      defaultValue() {
        if (this.instrument.name) {
          return this.instrument.name;
        }

        return '';
      },
    },
    [...]
  };
</script>
```

This is a parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <instrument v-for="(instrument, index) in instruments"
          :key="instrument.name"
          :instrument="instrument"
          :placeholder="$t('change_instrument')"
          :isNeedAutosuggest="true" /> <!--that flag should manage an autosuggest option-->
    <instrument v-if="instruments.length < maxInstruments"
          ref="newInstrument"
          :isNeedAutosuggest="true" <!-- here too -->
          :placeholder="$t('instrument-panel.ADD_INSTRUMENT')" />
  </div>
</template>
```

The main issues are I have so many `autosuggest`s in DOM as I have `instruments`. In other words, there is should be 1 `autosuggest` component when the option is `true`. Moving `autosuggest` to the parent level is not good because of flexibility and a lot of logically connected with `c-input`.

Have you any ideas to do it?

[UPDATE]

Here is how I've solve this;

I created an another component that wraps `input` and `autosuggest` components. If I need need an `input` with `autosuggest` I will use this one, either I will use a simple `input`.

```
/* wrapper.vue  - inserted into the  Instrument.vue*/
<template>
  <span>
    <fc-input ref="input"
      :values="value"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :isloading="isloading"
      @input="onInput"
      @changeInput="$emit('change', $event)"
      @resetInput="onResetInput" />
    <fc-autosuggest 
      v-if="isSuggestsExist"
      :suggests="suggests"
    />
  </span>
</template>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem... you just want to have 1 autosuggest component active, no matter how many instruments you have, but still having the autossugests component inside your instrument component?

Comment: @CodeHacker Yes, because I wanna make `instrument` reusable. Also I may use `instruments` without `autosuggest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you create a function inside each `instrument` component, which will call the parent component and search the first component `instrument` to find `autosuggest`. Function will be like that:

```
name: 'instrument',
...
computed: {
    autosuggestComponent () {

        // this is a pseudo code
        const parentChildrenComponents = this.$parent.children();
        const firstChild = parentChildrenComponents[0];
        const autosuggestEl = firstChild.$el.getElementsByTagName('autosuggest')[0];

        // return Vue component
        return autosuggestEl.__vue__;
    }   
},
methods: {
    useAutosuggestComponent () {
        this.autosuggestComponent.inputValue = this.inputValue;
        this.autosuggestComponent.suggests = [{...}];
    }
}
```

This solution is not so beautiful, but it allows to keep the logic inside the `instrument` component.

But my advice is create some parent component which will contain `instrument` components and I suggest to work with `autosuggest` through the parent. You can create `autosuggest` component in the parent and pass it to the children `instrument`s. And if `instrument` doesn't receive a link to a `autosuggest` (in props), than it will create `autosuggest` inside itself. It will allow to use `instrument` for different conditions.

Let me know if I need to explain my idea carefully.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean saying "And if instrument doesn't receive a link to a autosuggest (in props), than it will create autosuggest inside itself."
How it should work?

Comment: I mean you can pass an autosuggest component as prop, like `<instrument ... :instrument="instrument" :autosuggest="autosuggestComponent"/>`. And in the controller of the `instrument` component you can check and if the property `autosuggest` exists, then the component should use it, otherwise you need to create `autosuggest` inside the `instrument`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll provide my solution in [UPDATE] section of my question.